# will sql server 2008 lock source table while copying table from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a products table with 42 million records on our production db. 
For indexing and backup purposes we created another database on the same box called "ProductsDB"

If I import all records of products table with SSMS import wizard from DB1 to DB2 will it create any lock or slowness on DB1 (production)?

I do not care about DB2(ProductsDB) in terms of locks or slowness which will not be accessible until we adjust our code.

---

This is not a valid answer but my experince:

Since I could not find "exact" answer to my question (I searched a lot online) I took the risk and used Import wizard on this table. It took less than 5 minutes to complete and did not notice and performance/lock issue both on web server or database server.

Cons of this transaction;
- It did not create any primary keys
- It did not create any existing indexes from source table

I will need to create them again, but still it is fine and that was what I want.

Hope this will help for future references, I will keep searching for it.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) article may help you.

Part of it:

`Bulk Update Locks
Bulk update (BU) locks are used when bulk copying data into a table and either the TABLOCK hint is specified or the table lock on bulk load table option is set using sp_tableoption. Bulk update (BU) locks allow processes to bulk copy data concurrently into the same table while preventing other processes that are not bulk copying data from accessing the table.`

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Table Hints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) to prevent SQL Server taking locks on the data. NOLOCK for example.

Beware though that this can be very dangerous as you may end up reading uncommitted data which is subsequently rolled back; so know what you are doing and be careful.